# Confusion with use of Could Have + P.P

Tags: modal-verbs, conditionals, auxiliary-verbs

Let's suppose I have two simple sentences:

> **1**. I could run faster than Bob.
>   **2**. I could have run faster than Bob.

The first sentence can have the following meaning:

**[1a]** I was able to run faster than Bob yesterday but I can't today.
**[1b]** I could run faster than Bob now or in the future.

Whereas the second example means:

**[2a]** I didn't run faster than Bob, but I would have probably run faster under certain circumstances.
**[2b]** [Is there any other meaning?]

Comment: [2b] Yes, Bob ran a good race, but let's wait until all the times are posted. It's always a bit tricky to say who did best with time trials. _I_ could have run faster than Bob.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth so it also shows uncertainty, possibility which doesn't require a condition ? it means that there might have been a good chance that I ran faster than Bob, right?

Comment: [2a'] The race started 4 hours ago and lasted 5 minutes. Bob and I ran in it. He ran faster than I did (though I could have beaten him if I'd wanted to). // [2b'] The race finished 8 minutes ago, but was run as a time trial. Bob and I ran in it, but the times haven't been posted yet. I could have run faster than Bob – or he could have run faster than me. We'll soon find out which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, *could*, the preterite form of the modal verb *can* be used in two different types of constructions. First (reading a), it's interpreted as referring to past time (the most common use for the preterite). We'll call it a past tense construction. Then second (reading b), it's used to express modality (or "mood" in traditional grammar) and not time; specifically, the speaker's judgment about what is possible. This is called a modal preterite construction.

In the second example, only the modal preterite meaning is available because *have + V* has restricted distribution because it has a *stative* aspectual class (see Vendler's (1957) paper *[Verbs and Times](http://semantics.uchicago.edu/scalarchange/vendler57.pdf)* on this topic).

For example, you can use the progressive tense with non-stative verbs:

> Thomas is running right now.
>  Thomas is thinking right now.

But not with stative verbs:

> *Thomas is knowing the answer.
>   *Thomas is believing in miracles.
>   *Thomas is having killed a bear.

Interestingly, consider that:

> Thomas could know the answer.

...has only one reading (the speaker thinks it's possible that he knows the answer), while "Thomas could run faster" has two readings (at a specific time in the past something happened that let him run faster, or the speaker judges that he is (now or in the near future) able to run faster).

I wonder whether this has been remarked upon as a test for stative aspect before.

Comment: So sentence 2 is an example of the modal preterite, which conveys only modality (here, possibility or ability) and not time? Unfortunately for this claim, *I could have run faster than Bob* covers a specific time span in the past. It's the construction in sentence 1 that needn't be temporally anchored. The response "You could be right" can apply to a past statement or a prediction, or it can express a stative present.

Comment: @deadrat the embedded phrase *have run faster than Bob* has perfect tense, so it's necessarily interpreted as referring to a time frame. So the time reference doesn't come from *could*. That might be another reason why the past tense reading is blocked.

Comment: Point taken....